# Unable to read requests HTML response from a URL

Tags: python-3.x, session, cookies, python-requests, ddos

I am using python requests library for making http requests. For this website : https://www.epi.org/resources/budget/ i am unable to read the HTML response as it is not human readable , looks like its protected by cloudfare ddos protection . Here is my simple code below.

```
import requests

headers = {'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
           'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8',
           'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
           'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'}

s = requests.Session()
a = s.get('https://www.epi.org/resources/budget/',headers=headers)
print (a.text)
```

The response HTML looks like this : https://justpaste.it/6ie73

Answer (score 0):

The reason why got unreadable content is `Accept-Encoding`. Differ from browser, if Python got `gzip` response we have to unpack it by ourselves. Also `br` need to do so but with different module `brotl` . So you should set `'Accept-Encoding': 'default'`. Btw, if you need full content that rendering is necessary.